# Angucomplete-alt local-data fires server request

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, autocomplete

As per the decoumentation, I have specified the directive in my HTML as follows:

```
<div angucomplete-alt
    id="keyword"
    input-name="keyword"
    placeholder="Job title or keywords"
    pause="100"
    selected-object="selectedJob"
    local-data="jobs"
    search-fields="name"
    title-field="name"
    minlength="2"
    input-class="form-control">
</div>
```

Specifying local-data and search-fields. In my controller I have:

```
$scope.jobs = [
    {"name": ".Net Developer"},
    {"name": "Account Coordinator"},
    {"name": "Account Director"},
    {"name": "Account Executive"},
    {"name": "Account Executive Sales"}.
    ...
];

$scope.selectedJob = function($item) {
    $log.info('$scope.selectedJob()', $item);
};
```

But when I type on the field, an XHR request goes out to */undefinedWHATEVER_I_TYPED* which is of course 404. No results from my jobs array are shown...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any luck with this?  I'm getting the same result.

Comment: @6006604 I was using the angucomplete-alt directive outside of the scope of the controller, so the jobs local-data object was null and the plugin was calling remote instead with undefined followed by what I typed. Does this make sense? Hope this helps.

Comment: @izk, you are right!

Answer (score 0):

Late answer,Still if someone encounter this issue just enable cors in browser if you are calling api from localhost.